# Best way to use Windows' RAID 1 to have an hot backup

Tags: windows, backup, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I'm looking for a way to direct Win10 Pro RAID system to direct the reads to the fast drive in the mirror

I'm on Windows 10 PRO and have regular (but not too frequent) backups of my system.
The system consists mainly of:

- 2Tb NVME main drive (Samsung PRO)
- 2Tb NVME complimentary drive (non-pro)

Backups are a cool thing but take time and are always pretty annoying to execute (with 4tb of data) and never totally up-to-date. I've already experimented SSD failure and it's sudden and very annoying.

Given the current SSD prices I'm considering buying a cheap 4Tb SATA SSD (no more NVME slots here) and configure both the boot and complimentary drive to be mirrored by windows to the cheaper SATA SSD.

So the recipe would be:

- Add new 4Tb SATA SSD
- Convert all the disks to dynamic (already GPT)
- Add mirror to each partition using the new disk

However based on googling around this would reduce both read and write performance to the ones of the SATA disk!
I'm looking for a way to tell windows that the new mirrors should be treated as secondary and thus all writes should be synced there but reads should always go to the NVME disks.

**Question**: any way to instruct the windows RAID Mirroring system to have a preference for a specific drive when reading?

**Optionally**: A pleasant addition would be to be able to tell Windows to queue the writes to the second drive while declaring the write completed once it's completed on the first drive. Since I'm using an UPS the risk of misalignment would be acceptable.

**Note 1**: I'm not looking for a backup solution since I'm already performing backups, I'm willing top have a live "almost zero downtime" solution

**Note 2**: I've already looked into utilities like [RealTimeSync](https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=realtimesync) but they are not fit for mirroring advanced disk content and OS disk (NTFS attributes and streams, protected system folders etc...)

Comment: "RAID 1 to have a hot backup" – [The mandatory "RAID is not a backup" link](https://serverfault.com/q/2888/1044055).

Comment: :-) yep: the point here is to have a live second copy, not a backup, the title is somewhat misleading but the description clarifies it extensively